# Platform for e-book publishing and editing

Tags: web-apps, ebooks

One customer came to me with a very interesting need. **He has a published book**, and the **digital "source"** of it, and he wants a software/platform that basically could enable him to **publish** that e-book online and let him make **changes and revisions** over time.

As this could be or not a specific requirement, I'm thinking if there couldn't be anything out there that could satisfy at least most of his needs.

**Here is the detailed requirements:**

- It needs to be an online platform
- It has to let him upload his book at the current state
- It has to let him make changes on the e-book online (like making corrections, adding new content etc.)
- It should have the option for him to either block copy paste of the e-book text from the users or just let them copy a reduced portion of it (like N words or so). *Printscreen is not a concern*.
- **And I think this is tricky:** It shouldn't publish the book publicly... It should, in some way, let only authorized users access it.

**Notes**

- No need for e-book download (for now). The users should only view it online.
- It could be either an online service or a self-hosted app
- It should be interesting if the software could display customizable watermarks along with the pages, to disencourage users to printscreen them (that's from me, he hadn't mentioned it).

Comment: Do you want it to be only viewable online or downloadable (with DRM?)? If downloadable what format(s)?

Comment: Only viewable online. No need for download.

Comment: Should it be a service or a self-hosted app, or doesn’t matter?

Comment: Either way could work for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [Issuu](http://issuu.com/) should match your requirements. *One small note: I have used it as a consumer not a publisher.* As a reader I have been very satisfied with performance and stability.

In regards to [pricing](http://issuu.com/pricing), there is a free version but I think that last requirement will need a paid version; they have two plans and I think you will require the more expensive - $39/month - free 1 month trial available though.

To go over your requirements:

- *It needs to be an online platform:* Yes.
- *It has to let him upload his book at the current state:* Yes
- *It has to let him make changes on the e-book online (like making corrections, adding new content etc.):* I don't *think so* (the problem with recommending something based on using it in a different mode).
- *It should have the option for him to either block copy paste of the e-book text from the users or just let them copy a reduced portion of it (like N words or so). Printscreen is not a concern.*: Yes - don't see it in the docs but for example you can see that is the case [here](http://www.sookenewsmirror.com/eeditions/?iid=i20140319070629209).
- *And I think this is tricky: It shouldn't publish the book publicly... It should, in some way, let only authorized users access it.:* Yes it has an [option to be unlisted and an option for subscribers](http://issuu.com/feature-index); if you combine those I'm fairly confident you can get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll evaluate while waiting for some other thoughts :)

Answer (score 2):

[FastPencil.com](http://www.fastpencil.com/)

- It needs to be an online platform: yes
- It has to let him upload his book at the current state: Yes. You can import evernote or blog posts or MS Word, or OpenOffice Writer. no PDF, one chapter at a time.
- It has to let him make changes on the e-book online (like making corrections, adding new content etc.) : yes
- It should have the option for him to either block copy paste of the e-book text from the users or just let them copy a reduced portion of it (like N words or so). *Printscreen is not a concern*. : yes
- **And I think this is tricky:** It shouldn't publish the book publicly... It should, in some way, let only authorized users access it. : yes, you can control who sees what.

**Notes**

- No need for e-book download (for now). The users should only view it online: yes
- It could be either an online service or a self-hosted app: okay so yes
- It should be interesting if the software could display customizable watermarks along with the pages, to disencourage users to printscreen them (that's from me, he hadn't mentioned it). : I don't know about that